# Where do I get my username and password for solo mining?

Tags: miner-configuration

I downloaded Bitcoin-Qt and synched.  I downloaded pyminer to help me understand the mining process.  But I need a username and password.  Where do I get them for solo mining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a file named `bitcoin.conf` [to your data directory](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory) with the following values:

```
 # server=1 tells Bitcoin-QT to accept JSON-RPC commands.
 server=1

 # You must set rpcuser and rpcpassword to secure the JSON-RPC api
 rpcuser=user
 rpcpassword=<a password you make up>
```

Tell pyminer to mine at localhost with the password/username combo you just used.

Comment: I'm on OSX.  Where does the bitcoin.conf file go so Bitcoin-QT will pick it up?

Comment: @dacracot In your data directory. [See this page.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory)

Answer (score 2):

You just make them up. They just need to match on both ends (the bitcoin program and the mining program).

Comment: But the Bitcoin-Qt program never asked me to create one.  I looked for it, and found nothing.

Comment: It's in [the documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf).

Comment: While I appreciate your response and that I should RTFM, so much documentation and terminology is rather obtuse for someone new to the process.  A more directed response, as given by Nick ODell, saved me from reading much that was not applicable and solved my problem.